# Margin/Space Beween Embedded Report & "iframe" & Full Screen Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have embedded my PowerBI report by using the ReactJS.

The report is rendered as below HTML structure :

```
<iframe className="power-bi-iframe">
  <!-- REPORT HERE -->
</iframe>
```

[image]

I am getting the blank space/margin between the iframe and thr PowerBI report.

Is there any way to remove it & Show the full screen report on the web?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the report display to FitToWidth and . Pass the Updated the settings while embedding the report or using `updateSettings(settings)` during runtime.

```
   const settings = {
     layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
     customLayout: {
       displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToWidth,
     },
   };
```

References:
[Personalize Report layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/custom-layout#custom-layout-interface-definition)

Comment: LMK , if it works or still have problem with display